# Can Gstreamer take in a single http URL that is an image that updates every time it is requested (upto 10fps)?

Tags: image, opencv, http, gstreamer, rtsp

I have a camera that only outputs an image stream via http url every time it is requested. I want to turn this into a video stream to run analysis on it. I can run this stream in a loop using opencv and imread but I would prefer to run it in gstreamer natively for my application. I am using python.

I tried videowriter from opencv to gstreamer but see no activity on port specified. I have also tried opencv to an rtsp server to then pipe into gstreamer but this slow and prone to dropping out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an element in gstreamer called curlhttpsrc, the following gst-launch-1.0 string can help you:

```
gst-launch-1.0 curlhttpsrc location="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" ! image/png ! filesink location=wiki.png -e
```